# ResultSet.getFloat return 0 instead of NULL

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am using JDBC `ResultSet` to get records from database. But

```
ResultSet.getFloat() //returns 0 for NULL value.
```

Is there any way to get `null` value using `getFloat()` or an alternate solution?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `ResultSet#getObject` and type cast it to `Float`. Anyway, I would recommend you to retrieve the data as `BigDecima` rather than `Float` or `Double`.

Answer (score 12):

> is there any way to get NULL value using getFloat(); or any other alternate solution.

Yes. You can call [`ResultSet.wasNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull--) which *reports whether the last column read had a value of `SQL NULL`. Note that you must first call one of the getter methods on a column to try to read its value and then call the method `wasNull` to see if the value read was `SQL NULL`.*

Comment: @Cool Then call `wasNull()` after (which will tell you if that was actually a null).

Comment: ResultSet.GetFloat() - which returns - 0 if(ResultSet.wasNull()) this condition will be false as value return was 0. So not sure if wasNull method check for the value which is return or value which is actually in database.

Comment: @Cool It shouldn't, the JDBC specification requires that drivers return `true` if the last read value was `null` (you may realise that primitives like `float` can never be `null`, that is also the reason the API documentation of [`getFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getFloat-int-) says _"Returns: the column value; if the value is SQL `NULL`, the value returned is `0`"_). If `wasNull()` doesn't return `true` then either the column wasn't null, or there is a bug in the driver you use.

Answer (score 8):

You need to call [ResultSet.wasNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) to test whether the last column read had a value of SQL NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Just a different take on this:

```
ResultSet.getString("columnName")
```

will return a null or the value in the column. You can convert the value to a Float if the return from `getString` is non-null.